# Making JavaScript items independent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a jQuery script to expand/collapse a div on a page an it works perfectly. I'm now trying to replicate the code so there are two divs which do the same but I want them to be independent however when I click one, both open/close. Just wondering what i'm doing wrong?

So far, I have the following HTML:

```
    <div class="infoToggle1">
        <div class="panel-controller">
            <div class="tab-controller1">
                <span class="close">CLOSE</span>
                <span class="show">MORE INFO</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-content1">
            Content goes here
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="infoToggle2">
        <div class="panel-controller">
            <div class="tab-controller2">
                <span class="close">CLOSE</span>
                <span class="show">MORE INFO</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-content2">
            Content goes here
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the following jQuery code:

```
(function($) {

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        Panel.init();


        $(document).on('click', '.tab-controller1, .tab-controller2', function() {
             Panel.togglePanel();
        });

    });

    var Panel = {

        isVisible : false,
        showMessage : null,
        hideMessage : null,
        animationDuration : 300,
        animationEasing : 'linear',

        init: function() {
            Panel.hidePanel();
        },

        hidePanel : function() {
            $('.infoToggle1, .infoToggle2').animate({
                bottom : -(Panel.getAnimationOffset())
            }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
                Panel.isVisible = false;
                Panel.updateTabMessage();
            });
        },

        showPanel : function() {
            $('.infoToggle1, .infoToggle2').animate({
                bottom : 0
            }, Panel.animationDuration, Panel.animationEasing, function() {
                Panel.isVisible = true;
                Panel.updateTabMessage();
            });
        },

        togglePanel : function() {
            ((this.isVisible) ? this.hidePanel : this.showPanel)();
        },

        updateTabMessage : function() {
            if (this.isVisible) {
                $('.tab-controller1 .close, .tab-controller2 .close').show();
                $('.tab-controller1 .show, .tab-controller2 .show').hide();
            } else {
                $('.tab-controller1 .close, .tab-controller2 .close').hide();
                $('.tab-controller1 .show, .tab-controller2 .show').show();
            }
        },

        getAnimationOffset : function() {
            return $('.panel-content1, .panel-content2').height();
        }

    }

})(jQuery);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PseudoNinja is right. If you want two seperate actors, you need to pluginize your script. The right boilerplate for your code seems to be this: http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-revisited/

Comment: Are you allowed to refactor your code/markup at all? I've got a solution that I could post but it's a fairly decent overhaul so it editing the base code/markup is out of the question it won't be of much help.

Comment: This may work for you but it's a large deviation from your original code: [jsfiddle.net...](https://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/wuogq4ve/1/)

Comment: Also, as a rule of thumb, if you need to add numbers to the end of your classes, then you're probably better off using an `id` instead. Know though that this is relative to the situation and may not be suitable for all circumstances but I can't think of a case where incrementing classes would be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need two Panel objects as each needs its own settings for `isVisible` and several class names. For that you could turn the `Panel` object to a constructor, which you pass a number (1 or 2). That constructor would return the object as you had it, but with the particularities that apply only to the first element structure. If you call that constructor again with the other number, you would get the object you will need to manipulate (and keep state of) the second structure.

Your code could then look like this (not tested):

```
(function($) {

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var panel1 = new Panel(1),
            panel2 = new Panel(2);

        $(document).on('click', '.tab-controller1', function() {
             panel1.togglePanel();
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.tab-controller2', function() {
             panel2.togglePanel();
        });
    });

    // Constructor. Needs to get the number 1 or 2
    function Panel(num) {
        var that = this; // Remember the object that is created here
        Object.assign(that, {
            isVisible : false,
            showMessage : null,
            hideMessage : null,
            animationDuration : 300,
            animationEasing : 'linear',

            init: function() {
                that.hidePanel();
            },

            hidePanel : function() {
                // Use number to address the correct class, here and below.
                $('.infoToggle' + num).animate({
                    bottom : -(that.getAnimationOffset())
                }, that.animationDuration, that.animationEasing, function() {
                    that.isVisible = false;
                    that.updateTabMessage();
                });
            },

            showPanel : function() {
                $('.infoToggle' + num).animate({
                    bottom : 0
                }, that.animationDuration, that.animationEasing, function() {
                    that.isVisible = true;
                    that.updateTabMessage();
                });
            },

            togglePanel : function() {
                (that.isVisible ? that.hidePanel : that.showPanel)();
            },

            updateTabMessage : function() {
                if (that.isVisible) {
                    $('.tab-controller' + num + ' .close').show();
                    $('.tab-controller' + num + ' .show').hide();
                } else {
                    $('.tab-controller' + num + ' .close').hide();
                    $('.tab-controller' + num + ' .show').show();
                }
            },

            getAnimationOffset : function() {
                return $('.panel-content' + num).height();
            }
        });
        // call init here, which will execute when you do `new Panel`:
        that.init();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. trincot, your solution worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a class selector for your open/close animation try focusing on referencing your element in relation to the item clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your code for showing and hiding the panels. In both of them, you have:

```
$('.infoToggle1, .infoToggle2')
```

as your jQuery selector. This selector is selecting BOTH panels and calling `.animate()` on both of them at once. It cannot tell the difference between which one you clicked.

A solution may be to pass in the container you want each button to animate.

```
    $(document).on('click', '.tab-controller1', function() {
         Panel.togglePanel('.infotoggle1');
    })
    .on('click', '.tab-controller2', function() {
         Panel.togglePanel('.infotoggle2');
    });
```

And of course tweak `Panel.togglePanel()` to use the new parameters as the jQuery selector.

There is surely a quicker/cleaner way but this should get you started.